# How to change Gridview's cell colour dynamically?

Tags: android, gridview

I am developing a simple android application for learning gridview. My requirement is to create a 2x2 grid which changes colours dynamically like a serial light circuit one by one, and others should be in white colour.

Please suggest a way to do this.

Comment: What you did till now add your code here?

Comment: get position from Grid view and change background color randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom  ArrayAdapter

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, student_array) {
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    int color = 0x00FFFFFF; // Transparent
    if (condition) {
      color = 0x00000000; // Black
    }

    view.setBackgroundColor(color);

    return view;
  }
};
```

Comment: @GauthamRajAyyapparaj for 4 colours you can try this:
if (pos%4 == 0) {
      color = 0x00000000; // Black
}else if(pos%4 == 1){
      color = set color2; 
}else if(pos%4 == 2){
      color = set color3; 
}else if(pos%4 == 3){
      color = set color4; 
}

Comment: @GauthamRajAyyapparaj It is also dynamic. Suppose you have 20 items in your grid and four colours are RED,  BLUE, BLACK and WHITE. Then every 4 items repeat these colours.